# Hibernate: Select Parent with Children Conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following tables:

**HEADER**

```
---------------------------------
ID             |      STATUS
---------------------------------
1              |        A
---------------------------------
2              |        B
---------------------------------
```

**DATA**

```
--------------------------------------------------
ID         |  HEADER_ID    |    DKEY    |   DVALUE
--------------------------------------------------
1          |      1        |    Age     |    90
--------------------------------------------------
2          |      1        |    Gender  |    M
--------------------------------------------------
3          |      1        |    Score   |    1000
--------------------------------------------------
1          |      2        |    Age     |    8
--------------------------------------------------
2          |      2        |    Gender  |    M
--------------------------------------------------
3          |      2        |    Score   |    0
--------------------------------------------------
```

My JPA classes are:

```
**@Entity
@Table (name="HEADER")
public class Header {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column (name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="header")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<Data> dataList;

    --- getters and Setters ---
}


@Entity
@Table (name="DATA")
publi class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEADER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Header header;

    @Column (name="DKEY")
    private String key;

    @Column (name="DVALUE")
    private String value;
}**
```

Now,  my problem is, I want to select a Header with Data that has "Age" equals to "90" and "Gender" equals to "M" using hibernate.
I tried the below approach:

**select distinct h from Header h left join  h.dataList dl where  (dl.key = 'Age' and   dl.value = '90') and (dl.key = 'Gender' and   dl.value = 'M')**

This returns me nothing because the condition "(dl.key = 'Age' and   dl.value = '90') and (dl.key = 'Gender' and   dl.value = 'M')" is executed in one "DATA" record which will always yield to false.

If i put or, "(dl.key = 'Age' and   dl.value = '90') or (dl.key = 'Gender' and   dl.value = 'M')"  the result is wrong since I wanted to get those Header that Data satisfies Age and Gender conditions.

I had hours of headache because of this issue and I am out of solutions to try anymore.  Hope someone could point me to the right direction/solution.

Thank yo so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may try rewrite it this way:

```
select distinct h from Header as h 
where h.id in 
    (select dl.header.id from Data as dl where dl.key = 'Age' and dl.value = '90') 
and h.id in 
    (select dl.header.id from Data as dl where dl.key = 'Gender' and dl.value = 'M')
```